# Excel VBA find the column in a Range("H2:FA2") with any cell that has a value of "2"

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find the column in a Range("H2:FA2") with any cell in that range that has a value of "2" then set that colums rows (i.e. 3,15,16,17,18,19,20,22,24,27,28,30,32,35,38,41,44,47,50,53,56,59,62,65,68,71,74,77,80,83,86) to a value of  zero.

I tried modifying the code below which works for a single row,but not much luck.
I am not sure of the best approach using arrays?

If I could set a variable to equal the column name based on the located cell from my searched range then use that to loop thru my data set?

```
Sub test()      
Dim r As Range, cell As Range, mynumber As Long    

 Set r = Sheets("Pending Change Order Detail").Range("H2:FA2")    
mynumber = 0    
For Each cell In r    
        If cell.Value = 2 Then    
            cell.Value = mynumber    
    End If    
    Next    
End Sub
```

What I ended up doing is this:

```
    Sub setcolumtozero()
   'setcolumtozero Macro
   'set specific rows to zero if the column has a 2 in range (column,2)
Dim mycolumn  As Range, cell As Range
Set mycolumn = Sheet10.Range("H2:FA2")
For Each cell In mycolumn
        If cell.Value = 2 Then
       Cells(3, cell.Column).Value = 0
       Cells(15, cell.Column).Value = 0
       Cells(16, cell.Column).Value = 0
       Cells(17, cell.Column).Value = 0
       Cells(18, cell.Column).Value = 0
       Cells(19, cell.Column).Value = 0
       Cells(20, cell.Column).Value = 0
       Cells(22, cell.Column).Value = 0
       Cells(24, cell.Column).Value = 0
       Cells(26, cell.Column).Value = 0
       Cells(27, cell.Column).Value = 0
       Cells(28, cell.Column).Value = 0
       Cells(30, cell.Column).Value = 0
       Cells(32, cell.Column).Value = 0
       Cells(35, cell.Column).Value = 0
       Cells(38, cell.Column).Value = 0
       Cells(41, cell.Column).Value = 0
       Cells(44, cell.Column).Value = 0
       Cells(47, cell.Column).Value = 0
       Cells(50, cell.Column).Value = 0
       Cells(53, cell.Column).Value = 0
       Cells(56, cell.Column).Value = 0
       Cells(59, cell.Column).Value = 0
       Cells(62, cell.Column).Value = 0
       Cells(65, cell.Column).Value = 0
       Cells(68, cell.Column).Value = 0
       Cells(71, cell.Column).Value = 0
       Cells(74, cell.Column).Value = 0
       Cells(77, cell.Column).Value = 0
       Cells(80, cell.Column).Value = 0
       Cells(83, cell.Column).Value = 0
       Cells(86, cell.Column).Value = 0
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I will try the other answers mentioned here as I would like to learn faster ways to getting the job done.

Comment: Try reformatting the code in your post to help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try locating the 2 and using that column's intersect with your rows to set the zeroes.

```
Sub findTwo()
    Dim c As Variant

    With Worksheets("sheet3")
        c = Application.Match(2, .Range("H2:FA2"), 0) + 7
        If Not IsError(c) Then
             Intersect(.Columns(c), Union(.Range("3:3,15:20,22:22,24:24,27:28,30:30,32:32"), _
                                          .Range("35:35,38:38,41:41,44:44,47:47,50:50,53:53"), _
                                          .Range("56:56,59:59,62:62,65:65,68:68,71:71,74:74"), _
                                          .Range("77:77,80:80,83:83,86:86"))) = 0
       End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate both rows and columns in order to iterate through the whole range.
And you can name a cell, like you normally do in Excel, and then access it by using:

Dim MyRange as Range

Set MyRange = Range("MyNamedRange")

To iterate both rows and columns:

For Each row in MyRange

For Each cell in row

'Do something on cell ...

Next cell

Next row

If you're dealing with tons of numbers, then this approach is not that good. If you wish it to be faster, work with RangeToArray and vice versa. For more information - http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx